# `File.enum_for(:readlines, ...)` not enumerating

Tags: ruby, enumerator

Why does this enumerator unexpectedly return an empty array:

```
> File.enum_for(:readlines, '/usr/share/dict/words').take(1)
=> []
```

while this one returns properly:

```
File.enum_for(:readlines, "/usr/share/dict/words").each{}.take(1)
=> ["A\n"]
```

For comparison, other enumerators will work without the `each`:

```
> "abc".enum_for(:each_byte).take(1)
=> [97]
```

What's really odd in the `File.readlines` case is that the body of the `each` doesn't actually get executed:

```
File.enum_for(:readlines, "/usr/share/dict/words").
     each{|e| p e; raise "stop" }.take(2)
=> ["A\n", "a\n"]
```

This is on ruby 2.5.3. I tried the code both in `pry` and in a `ruby -e` one-liner, with the same results.

Comment: This is a great question. Obviously academic as `File.foreach` will return the appropriate enumerator but this is interesting

Comment: looks to be something specific with `IO.readlines`, `IO.enum_for(:foreach, '/usr/share/dict/words').take(1); => ["A\n"]`; is it because `readlines` returns an array and `foreach` returns an enumerator?

Comment: @Anthony no, because `enum_for` is only needed for methods that don't return an enumerator. Its purpose is to "convert" a method-call that only yields into an enumerator.

Comment: @Anthony actually, you're on to something... still testing out the theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `enum_for`/`to_enum` only works with a method that `yield`s. Credit goes to @Anthony for making me realize this.

This is the equivalent of what I was trying to do:

```
# whoops, `to_a` doesn't yield
[1,2,3].enum_for(:to_a).take(1)
=> []

# Works, but `enum_for` isn't really meant for this, and it's very possible this should be
#  considered undefined behavior.
# In this case, as in `File.readlines`, the `each` block isn't really executed.
> [1,2,3].enum_for(:to_a).each{}.take(1)
=> [1]
```

Another interesting thing is that calling `each{}` on one of these "weird enumerators" seems to act as though the enum-ed method (e.g. `to_a`) were called directly. But of course this is pointless.

```
> arr = [1,2,3]
> arr.object_id
=> 70226978129700
> arr.to_a.object_id
=> 70226978129700
# same as calling `to_a` - doesn't create a new array!
> arr.enum_for(:to_a).each{}.object_id
=> 70226978129700
```

In the case of `File.readlines`, its implementation simply reads in the lines and returns them in a single array; it doesn't `yield` anything.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the `each` block isn't really executed", as `[1,2,3].enum_for(:to_a).each{} #=> [1, 2, 3]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland nothing is yielded to the block. However the block is required for Enumerator#each to return the result of the original method. Since this method includes a block check if the block is not provided then ruby just returns the Enumerator again so an empty block sort of tricks it into returning the result of the to_a in your case. Since to_a does not yield the arguments each does not either. Basically the same as calling to_a with a block argument it is not invalid just the block is ignored for all intents and purposes

Comment: Interesting!  Thanks for sharing what you found

Comment: @engineersmnky, yes, I understand. My only point was that since `[1,2,3].enum_for(:to_a).each #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:to_a>` and `[1,2,3].enum_for(:to_a).each{} #=> [1, 2, 3]`, one cannot say that "the `each` block isn't really executed".

Comment: @CarySwoveland I feel like you can say the block is not executed. How would you describe the block in this context. `a.to_a { puts 'a'}`? I would say it is not executed and the same goes for the above. The block is acknowledged but not executed

Comment: @engineersmnky, we may be dealing in semantics, but in your example the same value is returned with and without the block.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The "block" is the code inside the curly braces. Without the braces, the enum'ed method is *not* called. Without: `[1].enum_for(:to_a).each` (returns enumerator); With: `[1].enum_for(:to_a).each{}` (returns result of `to_a`). In the latter case, any code you put inside the braces will *not* be executed, but it's still necessary to provide a block (so that the enumerator will be able to detect that `block_given?` is true).

Comment: Yes, I understand that.